# Javascript word counter issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, counter

What I want to do is, to make counter of total entered words which will save results even after cleaning text area.

Please take a look at the result of code below: http://jsfiddle.net/mnvMn/5/

NOTE: If you want to fix this problem by changing setInterval(autoPost, 100); DON'T! Because I tested all available change(), paste(), keyUp().... functions. No one of them worked with mobile barcode scanner. Only setting interval works.

```
var form=$("#bcscanner"), ids=$('#itemids'), counter=0;
function count() {

    var value =$(ids).val().replace(" ", "").replace(/[\s,]+$/, '');
    var words = value.split(",");
    var numWords =words.length;
    if($(ids).val() === '') {
        numWords = 0;
    }
    return numWords;
}

function autoPost(){
    counter=count()+counter;
    $("#counter").html(count()+'/'+counter);
    if(count()==="10"){   
       ajaxpost();     
       $(ids).val('');
    }
}

$(document).ready(function () {   
    $( "input:submit, input:reset").button();

    setInterval(autoPost, 100);

});
```

Comment: What exactly is it not doing currently? You didn't tell us what the problem is yet (fiddle isn't working for me at the moment). Just by looking at your code, it looks like it would count letters instead of words since you are remving spaces, i guess depending on what is placed into the input.

Comment: @KevinB lets say user entered 10 words, after 10 words my script posts all eneterd words and cleans textarea. I want to show <current 10 word counter>/<total entered words counter>

Comment: As you're using an interval to process the input you'll have to check for an actual change in the data before counting. Try storing the previous value and on the next iteration check if the current value is not the previous and only if they are different, count words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a modified version of your fiddle that counts the total words correctly: http://jsfiddle.net/MuyaK/5/

You were updating the global counter on each update instead of tracking the total number of ten word counts.

Comment: No it was working well. Try to enter some word. And take a look at counter. You'll see what I'm talking about.  I want to show <current 10 word counter>/<total entered words counter>

Comment: I don't see any change. Just try to enter any word into textarea

Comment: And I'm splitting words by comma. Why you changed that?

Comment: Just didn't understand your original question. I've updated the response to only address the total word counting problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery plugin to count words, you can restrict typing either by character or words
http://qwertypants.me/counter/

Comment: Listen, I already made counter. I don't need any plug-in. Anyway thx